# How do I use jQuery new advanced ticker to read text from text file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying this code now in my website:

```
<script>
var file = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/test.txt";
function getFile(){
    $.get(file,function(txt){
        var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
        for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
            save(lines[i]);
          <ul class="newsticker">lines[i]</ul>
        }
    }); 
}
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/jquery.newsTicker.js"></script>

<script>
$('.newsticker').newsTicker({
    row_height: 48,
    max_rows: 2,
    speed: 6000,
    direction: 'up',
    duration: 400,
    autostart: 1,
    pauseOnHover: 0
});
</script>
```

But I don't see anything. The text suppose to scroll up.

In the original the code was:

```
<ul class="newsticker">
    <li>Etiam imperdiet volutpat libero eu tristique.</li>
    <li>Curabitur porttitor ante eget hendrerit adipiscing.</li>
    <li>Praesent ornare nisl lorem, ut condimentum lectus gravida ut.</li>
    <li>Nunc ultrices tortor eu massa placerat posuere.</li>
</ul>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/jquery.newsTicker.js"></script>

<script>
$('.newsticker').newsTicker({
    row_height: 48,
    max_rows: 2,
    speed: 6000,
    direction: 'up',
    duration: 400,
    autostart: 1,
    pauseOnHover: 0
});
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong ? I checked I the file test.txt exist and I can read it but the code :

```
<script>
    var file = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/test.txt";
    function getFile(){
        $.get(file,function(txt){
            var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
            for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
                save(lines[i]);
              <ul class="newsticker">lines[i]</ul>
            }
        }); 
    }
    </script>
```

Is not working I don't see anything. 
Tried to add in the FOR LOOP the line:

```
<ul class="newsticker">lines[i]</ul>
```

But I guess it's wrong.

EDIT**

The code is now look like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/jquery.newsTicker.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    var file = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/test.txt";
    $.get(file, function (txt) {
        var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
        $ul = $('<ul class="newsticker" />');
        for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
            //save(lines[i]); // not sure what this does
            $ul.append('<li>' + lines[i] + '</li>');
        }
        $ul.appendTo('body').newsTicker({
            row_height: 48,
            max_rows: 2,
            speed: 6000,
            direction: 'up',
            duration: 400,
            autostart: 1,
            pauseOnHover: 0
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

But it does nothing i don't see any text at all.

EDIT**

Opend the console dev on my website at: http://newsxpressmedia.com/
And i see this text in the console:

6
Consider using 'dppx' units instead of 'dpi', as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), not all, not all, not all, only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) (index):1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined (index):101
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/plugins/jquery-plugin-advanced-news-ticker  hope this will helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues. The first is that you need to create your `li` elements and append them to the dom. The second is that you aren't waiting for the ajax call to finish before setting up the newsticker plugin. I also don't see a reason to have the `getFile` function:

```
$(function() {
    var file = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/test.txt";
    $.get(file, function (txt) {
        var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
        $ul = $('<ul class="newsticker" />');
        for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
            //save(lines[i]); // not sure what this does
            $ul.append('<li>' + lines[i] + '</li>');
        }
        $ul.appendTo('body').newsTicker({
            row_height: 48,
            max_rows: 2,
            speed: 6000,
            direction: 'up',
            duration: 400,
            autostart: 1,
            pauseOnHover: 0
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Jason look at my question i edited it added the code how it looks now after changed it according to your answer. It does nothing i don't see any text at all.

Comment: @DanielLip Any errors in the error console of your browser's dev tools? Have you debugged the javascript and used `console.log()` statements to see where things are going wrong?

Comment: No i never tried it before. I dont know how to do it how to open the broswer console and not how/where to use the console.log() in the code.

Comment: Updated my question now with the error. What does it mean and how can i fix it ?